# Openflow touchAtIndex delegate method not triggered

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, coverflow

i followed this tutorial (http://github.com/tupps/OpenFlow) for creating cover-flow ,

but in open flow openflow library 'touchAtIndex' delegate method was not being called when taping the images.

any suggestions on to trigger that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i found another way to detect single tap on image . i created a custom button and placed it image zoomed area n given a tag value for each image n i presented a view on each image touch...

Answer (score 0):

```
[(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setViewDelegate:self];
```